# Qt3D Crashing when removing frame graph

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I'm trying to create an application using Qt3D that where I can create multiple view windows on the same scene.  I started with the code from the Qt3DWindow and the [Simple C++ Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3d-simple-cpp-example.html) and started moving things around.  What I figured is that each view window would define its own frame graph (just using a simple QForwardRenderer for now) and camera and then I would add each window's frame graph to the main frame graph in my scene.

Everything appears to be working fine as I create multiple windows, but when I close the windows and start removing frame graphs, the application crashes.  It's crashing on a background thread somewhere down in the Qt3DCore or Qt3DRender module and I can't get to the source code.  As I understand it I should be able to modify the frame graph dynamically at run time, but is that not thread safe?  Are you expected to wholesale replace one frame graph with another as opposed to modifying the active frame graph like I'm doing?

**--- Edit ---**

I did a little more testing and if I delay destroying the QWindow (i.e., the surface that it's trying to render to) a bit after removing its frame graph from the parent frame graph, I don't get the crash.  I *do* however get some warnings on the console that say:

> Qt3D.Renderer.Backend: bool __cdecl Qt3DRender::Render::GraphicsContext::makeCurrent(class QSurface *) makeCurrent failed

My guess is it's a threading issue, that the backend is still trying to use the QSurface to render to after it has been destroyed on the main thread.  I don't really like my solution (I just used a single shot timer to delay destroying the window by 1 second), but it's better than crashing.

**RenderWindow.h**

```
#ifndef RENDERWINDOW_H
#define RENDERWINDOW_H
#include <QWindow>
#include <Qt3DCore>
#include <Qt3DRender>
#include <Qt3DInput>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QForwardRenderer>

class RenderWindow : public QWindow
{
public:
  RenderWindow(QScreen* screen = nullptr);
  ~RenderWindow();

  Qt3DRender::QCamera* camera() const;
  Qt3DRender::QFrameGraphNode* frameGraph() const;

protected:
  void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *) override;

private:
  // Rendering
  Qt3DRender::QFrameGraphNode* mpFrameGraph;
  Qt3DRender::QCamera* mpCamera;

  static bool msFormatDefined;
};

#endif // RENDERWINDOW_H
```

**RenderWindow.cpp**

```
#include "renderwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

bool RenderWindow::msFormatDefined = false;

namespace
{
    // Different clear colors so that it's obvious each window is using a
    // different camera and frame graph.
    static QColor sClearColors[] = {
        Qt::darkBlue,
        Qt::blue,
        Qt::darkCyan,
        Qt::cyan
    };
    static int sViewCount = 0;
}

RenderWindow::RenderWindow(QScreen* screen)
    : QWindow(screen)
    , mpFrameGraph(nullptr)
    , mpCamera(new Qt3DRender::QCamera)
{
    setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);

    // Set the default surface format once
    if (!msFormatDefined)
    {
        QSurfaceFormat format;
        format.setVersion(4, 3);
        format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
        format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
        format.setSamples(4);
        format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
        setFormat(format);

        QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
        msFormatDefined = true;
    }

    // Camera
    mpCamera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    mpCamera->setPosition(QVector3D(0, 0, 40.0f));
    mpCamera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    // Frame Graph (using forward renderer for now)
    Qt3DExtras::QForwardRenderer* renderer = new Qt3DExtras::QForwardRenderer;
    renderer->setCamera(mpCamera);
    renderer->setSurface(this);
    renderer->setClearColor(sClearColors[sViewCount++ % 4]);
    mpFrameGraph = renderer;
}

RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()
{
    qDebug() << "start ~RenderWindow";

    // Unparent objects.  Probably not necessary but it makes me feel
    // good inside.
    mpFrameGraph->setParent(static_cast<Qt3DCore::QNode*>(nullptr));
    mpCamera->setParent(static_cast<Qt3DCore::QNode*>(nullptr));

    delete mpFrameGraph;
    delete mpCamera;

    qDebug() << "end ~RenderWindow";
}

Qt3DRender::QCamera* RenderWindow::camera() const
{
    return mpCamera;
}

Qt3DRender::QFrameGraphNode* RenderWindow::frameGraph() const
{
    return mpFrameGraph;
}

void RenderWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *)
{
    mpCamera->setAspectRatio((float)width()/(float)height());
}
```

**Scene.h**

```
#ifndef SCENE_H
#define SCENE_H
#include <Qt3DCore/QEntity>

#include <Qt3DInput/QInputAspect>

#include <Qt3DRender/QFrameGraphNode>
#include <Qt3DRender/QRenderAspect>
#include <Qt3DRender/QRenderSettings>

class RenderWindow;

class Scene
{
public:
    Scene();
    ~Scene();

    Qt3DCore::QEntityPtr rootNode() const;

    void addView(RenderWindow* window);

private:
    void setupScene();

private:
    Qt3DCore::QEntityPtr mpRoot;

    // Frame Graph
    Qt3DRender::QFrameGraphNode* mpFrameGraph;
    Qt3DRender::QRenderSettings* mpRenderSettings;

    // Aspects
    Qt3DCore::QAspectEngine* mpEngine;
    Qt3DRender::QRenderAspect* mpRenderAspect;
    Qt3DInput::QInputAspect* mpInputAspect;
};

#endif // SCENE_H
```

**Scene.cpp**

```
#include "scene.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

#include <Qt3DCore/QTransform>

#include <Qt3DRender/QClearBuffers>

#include <Qt3DExtras/QPhongMaterial>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QCylinderMesh>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QSphereMesh>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QTorusMesh>

#include "orbittransformcontroller.h"
#include "RenderWindow.h"

Scene::Scene()
    : mpRoot(nullptr)
    , mpFrameGraph(new Qt3DRender::QFrameGraphNode)
    , mpRenderSettings(new Qt3DRender::QRenderSettings)
    , mpEngine(new Qt3DCore::QAspectEngine)
    , mpRenderAspect(new Qt3DRender::QRenderAspect)
    , mpInputAspect(new Qt3DInput::QInputAspect)
{
    mpEngine->registerAspect(mpRenderAspect);

    mpRenderSettings->setActiveFrameGraph(mpFrameGraph);

    setupScene();

    mpRoot->addComponent(mpRenderSettings);
    mpEngine->setRootEntity(mpRoot);
}

Scene::~Scene()
{
    qDebug() << "start ~Scene";

    mpEngine->setRootEntity(Qt3DCore::QEntityPtr());
    mpRoot.clear();

    delete mpEngine;
    // mpRenderSettings and mpFrameGraph are children of the
    // root node and are automatically destroyed when it is.

    qDebug() << "end ~Scene";
}

Qt3DCore::QEntityPtr Scene::rootNode() const
{
    return mpRoot;
}

void Scene::addView(RenderWindow* window)
{
    // Add the window's frame graph to the main frame graph
    if (window->frameGraph())
    {
        window->frameGraph()->setParent(mpFrameGraph);
    }
}

void Scene::setupScene()
{
    mpRoot.reset(new Qt3DCore::QEntity);

    Qt3DCore::QEntity* entity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity;
    entity->setParent(mpRoot.data());

    // Create the material
    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(entity);
    material->setAmbient(Qt::black);
    material->setDiffuse(QColor(196, 196, 32));
    material->setSpecular(Qt::white);

    // Torrus
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *torusEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(entity);
    Qt3DExtras::QTorusMesh *torusMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QTorusMesh;
    torusMesh->setRadius(5);
    torusMesh->setMinorRadius(1);
    torusMesh->setRings(100);
    torusMesh->setSlices(20);

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *torusTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
    torusTransform->setScale3D(QVector3D(1.5, 1, 0.5));
    torusTransform->setRotation(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1, 0, 0), -45.0f));

    torusEntity->addComponent(torusMesh);
    torusEntity->addComponent(torusTransform);
    torusEntity->addComponent(material);

    // Sphere
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *sphereEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(entity);
    Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh *sphereMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh;
    sphereMesh->setRadius(3);

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *sphereTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
    /*OrbitTransformController *controller = new OrbitTransformController(sphereTransform);
    controller->setTarget(sphereTransform);
    controller->setRadius(20.0f);

    QPropertyAnimation *sphereRotateTransformAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(sphereTransform);
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setTargetObject(controller);
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setPropertyName("angle");
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setStartValue(QVariant::fromValue(0));
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setEndValue(QVariant::fromValue(360));
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setDuration(10000);
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->setLoopCount(-1);
    sphereRotateTransformAnimation->start();*/

    sphereEntity->addComponent(sphereMesh);
    sphereEntity->addComponent(sphereTransform);
    sphereEntity->addComponent(material);
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "scene.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void createWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Scene* scene;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "renderwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    scene(new Scene())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->createButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::createWindow);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    qDebug() << "~MainWindow";

    delete scene;
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::createWindow()
{
    RenderWindow* window = new RenderWindow();
    scene->addView(window);
    window->resize(640, 480);
    window->show();

    QVector3D pos[] = {
        QVector3D(0, 0, 40),
        QVector3D(0, 25, -30),
        QVector3D(-20, -20, -20),
        QVector3D(40, 0, 0)
    };
    static int count = 0;
    window->camera()->setPosition(pos[count++%4]);
    window->camera()->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    // Delete the window when it is closed.
    connect(window, &QWindow::visibilityChanged, this, [=](bool on)
    {
        if (!on)
            window->deleteLater();
    });
}
```

Comment: I really like Qt3D but the documentation is still very limited and most of the examples are for QML and for static scenes, so I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around how to do certain things.  If there's a better way to go to dynamically add and remove new render targets, I'm all ears.

Comment: I think you have come across one of the race conditions that we've been working to fix in Qt3D lately. The issue you're seeing might already have been fixed in Qt 5.11, but I'll need to test to verify that first. If you have the time, it would be great if you could file a bug report at https://bugreports.qt.io also, to improve the likelihood that it will be fixed in upcoming releases.

Comment: @dragly I have submitted a bug report to Qt already.

Answer (score 2):

I've thoroughly tested your example and draw the same conclusions. When you destroy the window too quickly, the application crashes, probably because Qt3D still tries to issue some OpenGL commands to the underlying QSurface. I think this is a bug that should be reported.

A 'cleaner' work-around of this problem could be to track the generated 3d windows in the main window. You could maintain a list of pointers to all windows that where generated (and probably closed by the user at the some point). The windows are finally destroyed in the destructor of the main window.

Comment: This is just a simple test application to play around with some aspects of Qt3D.  In my real application I would do a better job managing my objects.I don't like the idea of keeping unused windows around until the application itself finishes.  Is there any sort of notification from the frame graph or anything else when it is finished with a surface that I could trigger off of to know that it's safe to delete the window?

Comment: I totally agree with you, to keep the windows isn't rally a neat solution. I experimented a bit with the method deleteLater() which postpones the deletion of the window until the control returns to the event loop. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I was creating a class derived from Qt3DWindow in a dialog box so the user could preview the effects of the choices made, and the program crashed when the dialog exited. In fact on Windows this crash causes the debugger and Qt Creator to crash too!

I tried working around this in a variety of ways and some helped because it turns out that it is a threading issue that was fixed on the 23rd October:

https://github.com/qt/qt3d/commit/3314694004b825263c9b9f2d69bd85da806ccbbc

The fix is now to apply the patch, and recompile Qt. 5.11.3 (or perhaps 5.12) will be out quite soon I expect but this bug is a killer if you are using Qt3D in dialogs.